# Cordova App: "Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo"

Tags: android, class, cordova, android-activity, crash

I developed my first app using Cordova. Everytime I served the app on debug mode (by doing cordova run android --device) it worked perfectly on my phone. But when I finally compiled it and uploaded it to Google Play Store and donwnloaded it and installed it on my phone from there, the app crashed and gave me this message:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.sangenelo.miCarreraApp/com.sangenelo.miCarreraApp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sangenelo.miCarreraApp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sangenelo.miCarreraApp-_MQzKccxHMYXehf5nxINAg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sangenelo.miCarreraApp-_MQzKccxHMYXehf5nxINAg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3232)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3457)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sangenelo.miCarreraApp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sangenelo.miCarreraApp-_MQzKccxHMYXehf5nxINAg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sangenelo.miCarreraApp-_MQzKccxHMYXehf5nxINAg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
> at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:230)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
> at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1251)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3220)
> ... 11 more

It keeps crashing and giving that message. I've trying to find the cause but I couldn't find a way to solve it.

I use Microsoft Visual Studio Code.
You can find my app in [GitHub](https://github.com/sangenelo/MiCarreraApp)
Or even on the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sangenelo.miCarreraApp)

If you could give me a hand I would appreciate it so much, I'm very very new on app development so I'm kind of lost right now.